# Appending rows from a Google Sheet to an existing table in Big Query using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a Google Sheet from which I want to take a selection of cells and append them as rows to a table which already exists in Big Query. I have written the following code, which runs without any errors, but when I check the table in BQ, it doesn't update.

```
function myFunction() {

  var projectId = 'projectId'; 
  var datasetId = 'datasetId';
  var tableId = 'tableId';

  var fileId = 'fileId';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(21,2,sheet.getLastRow()-21,7);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var rowsCSV = values.join("\n");
  Logger.log(rowsCSV);

  function convertValuesToRows(rowsCSV) {
    var rows = [];  
    var headers = rowsCSV[0]; 


    for (var i = 1, numColumns = rowsCSV.length; i < numColumns; i++) {
      var row = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequestRows();
      row.json = rowsCSV[i].reduce(function(obj, value, index) {
        obj[headers[index]] = value;
        return obj
      }, {});
      rows.push(row);
    }; 
    return rows;
    }

  function bigqueryInsertData(rowsCSV, tableId) {
    var insertAllRequest = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequest();
    insertAllRequest.rows = convertValuesToRows(rowsCSV);     
    var response = BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll(insertAllRequest, projectId, datasetId, tableId);
    if (response.insertErrors) {
      Logger.log(response.insertErrors);
    }
  }

}
```

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: You never call `bigqueryInsertData` at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the rowsCSV to a blob allowed me to use the getDataAsString() method in the bigqueryInsertData function. I also manually named the headers to match the column names of the table in BigQuery. The final code looks like this, runs without errors and the BQ table updates successfully.

```
function myFunction() {

      var projectId = 'production-1077'; 
      var datasetId = 'alex_test';
      var tableId = 'Total_Jobs_Reporting_Table';

      var fileId = 'fileId';
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var range = sheet.getRange(21,2,sheet.getLastRow()-21,7);
      var values = range.getValues();
      var rowsCSV = values.join("\n");
      var data = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, 'application/octet-stream'); 

      function convertValuesToRows(data) {
        var rows = [];  
        var headers = ["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6","name7"] ; 


        for (var i = 1, numColumns = data.length; i < numColumns; i++) {
          var row = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequestRows();
          row.json = data[i].reduce(function(obj, value, index) {
            obj[headers[index]] = value;
            return obj
          }, {});
          rows.push(row);
        }; 
        return rows;
     }

     function bigqueryInsertData(data, tableId) {
       var insertAllRequest = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequest();
       insertAllRequest.rows = convertValuesToRows(data);     
       var response = BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll(insertAllRequest, projectId, datasetId, tableId);
       if (response.insertErrors) {
         Logger.log(response.insertErrors);
       }
    }

    bigqueryInsertData(Utilities.parseCsv(data.getDataAsString()), tableId);
}
```