# Google sheet to BigQuery by GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am following the instruction below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080633/appending-rows-from-a-google-sheet-to-an-existing-table-in-big-query-using-google) with following code ( to make a app script to send data to big query from google sheet ):

```
function myFunction() {

      var projectId = 'tcndata'; 
      var datasetId = 'dec06';
      var tableId = 'dec0601';

      var fileId = '1Mb7tN3xshHt0gpsxHkt5Ifje4xAeu7N9Vn_YEQAdcoc';
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
      var source = ss.getSheetByName("send");
      var dataToCopy = source.getRange('A2:D5');
      var values = dataToCopy.getValues();
      var rowsCSV = values.join("\n");
      var data = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, 'application/octet-stream'); 

      function convertValuesToRows(data) {
        var rows = [];  
        var headers = ["Contract","Product","Dest","QTY"] ; 


         for (var i = 1, numColumns = data.length; i < numColumns; i++) {
          var row = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequestRows();
          row.json = data[i].reduce(function(obj, value, index) {
            obj[headers[index]] = value;
            return obj
          }, {});
          rows.push(row);
        }; 
        return rows;
     }

     function bigqueryInsertData(data, tableId) {
       var insertAllRequest = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequest();
       insertAllRequest.rows = convertValuesToRows(data);     
       var response = BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll(insertAllRequest, projectId, datasetId, tableId);
       if (response.insertErrors) {
         Logger.log(response.insertErrors);
       }
    }

    bigqueryInsertData(Utilities.parseCsv(data.getDataAsString()), tableId);
}
'''
```

The script also no error but the big query no record data.

Any one can help, to figure out what is reason ?

Thank you

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: Many Thanks Raul for your help, but seem i can not fix my problem even i saw the log console even, but big query still no data. My purpose is appending data to exsiting table in bigquery from you sheet, each submit from google is few row ( < 10 rows ).

Comment: Do you have enough permissions to the dataset? You can test using an administrator account and check if you can insert data, in case that you can insert data is about permissions if not, is something else.

Comment: I use admin account to test,i will check more thanks for your following

Answer (score 0):

You could see these options:

- You should validate the headers’s name, as it needs to match the
  column names of the table in BigQuery
- You should validate converting the rowsCSV to a blob to use
  getDataAsString
- You should validate the name of the sheet is correct
  `ss.getSheetByName("send");` you can use `ss.getSheets()[0];`
- You should validate the range has data `source.getRange('A2:D5')`. You
  can use this format `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`.Yo can see more documentation about [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Another option is for you to load CSV data from Cloud Storage into a new BigQuery table by. You can see this example:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
 
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()
 
# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"
 
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"
 
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
 
load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
 
destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

You can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table).